# Match partial IP with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ip-address

In my index, I have an IP field. The type of the field is "ip".

I want to search all IPs who starts with "192.168"

All my tentative have failed with the following message:

> failed to parse ip [192.168], not a valid ip address

Is there a way of doing this or should I change the type of the field to "string"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use range query for example like:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "ip_addr": {
        "gte": "192.168.0.0",
        "lt":  "192.168.255.255"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of using a range...Thanks :)