# Wild card query on a field with Type Ip in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I have an index template having a field type Ip as shown below.

```
 "clientIpAddress": {
      "type": "ip"
  },
```

How can i search using  wildcard search query on such fields.I am trying the following search query.

```
"clientIpAddress":  "10.*"
```

> But I am getting error :
>   "'10.*' is not an IP string literal.

Need help to find the right wildcard query.

Comment: You could try use a range query like described here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057919/match-partial-ip-with-elasticsearch

Answer (score 2):

you have two option to search query for type IP:

### Method 1:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index_name/type_name/_search -d '{
"query": {
"query_string": {
  "query": "clientIpAddress:[192.168.1.100 TO 192.168.1.102]"
}
}
}'
```

### Method 2:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index_name/type_name/_search -d '{
"query": {
"range": {
  "add": {
    "gte": "192.168.1.100",
    "lte": "192.168.1.102"
  }
}
}
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.These solutions work well.But my requirement is to have an option of doing wildcard search like clientIpAddress:"*10.197*". Is that feature available with elastic search?